# Is there any SQL + Redis Hybrid ORM/OHM framework?

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, redis, jedis

I can't find any related frameworks. For example, a hybrid ORM/OHM framework for Hibernate and Jedis (JAVA Framework). Is there some reasons that this kind of framework didn't appear yet?

Comment: Does my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

Check

https://github.com/xetorthio/johm

> JOhm is a blazingly fast Object-Hash Mapping library for Java inspired by the awesome Ohm. The JOhm OHM is a modern-day avatar of the old ORM's like Hibernate with the difference being that we are not dealing with an RDBMS here but with a NoSQL rockstar.
>
> JOhm is a library for storing objects in Redis, a persistent key-value
>   database. JOhm is designed to be minimally-invasive and relies wholly
>   on reflection aided by annotation hooks for persistence. The
>   fundamental idea is to allow large existing codebases to easily plug
>   into Redis without the need to extend framework base classes or
>   provide excessive configuration metadata.
>
> Durable data storage is available via the Redis Append-only file
>   (AOF). The default persistence strategy is Snapshotting.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is the one of NoSQL database, and it doesn't support rich features provided by RDBs. (secondary index, grouping, query with multiple conditions, etc.) So naturally wrapping Redis operations with SQL doesn't make sense.

If you just want to have Object Mapper for Redis, spring-data-redis provides Serializer/Deserializer so you can store object to bytes in Redis, and load your data to object from Redis.